# Domain Admin Cleanup with Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm in the process of cleaning up my inherited Domain Admins group and remove service accounts that are no longer needed.  I'm trying to pull the group membership of the Domain Admins group and feed it into a `Get-ADUser`, with little success.

```psh
$name = Get-ADGroupMember "domain admins" | select -ExpandProperty Name
Foreach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -Like "$name"} -Properties * | FT Name, LastLogonDate
}
```

If I run the `Get-ADGroupMember` by itself it works.  If I run the `Get-ADUser` with a name from the list (instead of the `$name` variable) it works.  But when I attempt to tie them together it does not work.

Comment: I would suggest using SAMAccountname rather than Name since it has to be unique. Then you won't need a filter at all.

Comment: Also, presumably $name is an array. that won't work with a like filter anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am glad you were able to make it work but I would like to offer some advice. First don't use `-Properties *` when all you really needed was `LastLogonDate`. You are pulling more data than you need to. Also you don't even need the `ForEach` loop since `Get-Aduser` will accept the pipeline input very nicely.

```psh
Get-ADGroupMember "domain admins" | Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogonDate |
  Select Name,LastLogonDate
```

or if you really want console output, as supposed to standard output

```psh
Get-ADGroupMember "domain admins" | Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogonDate |
  Format-Table Name,LastLogonDate -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @EBGreen, your comment pointed me in the right direction.  I am able to get what I need with the following:

```psh
Get-ADGroupMember "domain admins" | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | % {
    $name=$_
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties *
} | FT Name, LastLogonDate -AutoSize
```